# Overloaded methods that handle subclasses of some abstract class

Tags: java

I have a generic `Person` class, and two types of people `Student` and `Teacher` that extends the `Person` class. I also have teaching sessions which  will store a list of students and a list of teachers that will be in that session.

```
class Person {}
class Student extends Person {}
class Teacher extends Person {}

class Session {
  List<Student> students = new ArrayList();
  List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList();

  // add a person to the teaching session.
  // They should be placed into the appropriate lists
  public void enroll(Person p)
  {
    if (p instanceof Student)
      students.add((Student) p)
    else if (p instanceof Teacher)
      teachers.add((Teacher) p)
  }
}
```

The idea is that some other code will have a list of people and iterate the list to enroll them into the appropriate sessions as needed. However, the `enroll` method currently explicitly checks the object's type, which to me is undesirable and seems like bad design.

I have tried writing the `enroll` method like this using method overloading, which looks a lot cleaner

```
public void enroll(Student p)
{
    students.add(p)
}

public void enroll(Teacher p)
{
    teachers.add(p)
}
```

but it seems like the code that iterates through the list of `Person` objects would need to then figure out whether the current person is a student or teacher instance, and type-cast appropriately before passing it to an `enroll` method.

Is there a way for me to design this so that I do not need to invoke `instanceof` at any point in time in my own code?

Comment: Just for completeness sake, and not a particularly good way to do it, but I should mention just casting it for adding and catching the `ClassCastException` thrown. You would do this assuming there are more students than teachers so the teachers are the ones that throw the exception.

Comment: What is the harm in using Generics here ?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the example accordingly to reflect the idea that the list of students will only hold `Student` instances while the list of teachers will only hold `Teacher` instances.

Comment: I will look into the visitor pattern and see how I can apply it in this situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `Session` needs to have an overloaded enroll method as in your question.
2. Add an `abstract enroll` method to `Person` class that takes `Session` as a parameter

   `public abstract void enroll (Session s);`
3. `Teacher` and `Student` each override `enroll`

   ```
   public void enroll (Session s) {
        s.enroll(this);
   }
   ```

Comment: I like this.  Note that you would still have `enroll(Person p)` in the `Session` which would be the call `{ p.enroll(this); }`

Comment: I didn't think of adding an `enroll` method to the `Person` class. Actually, that would probably be better design, since a Person would define how it would "enroll" in a session (eg: maybe it has to pay a fee first before picking a session), and a session would define how it "enrolls" a person into its session (eg: adding it to a list).

Comment: This is the correct solution. Note that it actually _is_ (a dedicated instance of) the Visitor pattern suggested by @millimoose in his/her comment to the original question.

Comment: This is called double dispatch which is a particular case of the visitor pattern. I still think that is not the right solution because the hierarchy is wrong. The "if" part can be resolved using double dispatch, or a test method... but is not the main issue of the design.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to add an `isTeacher()` method to the person class.

Here is a basic implemention (with the parts you already wrote left out)

```
abstract class Person {
  public abstract boolean isTeacher();
}

class Teacher extends Person {
  public boolean isTeacher() { return true; }
}

class Student extends Person {
  public boolean isTeacher() {return false; }
}

abstract class Session {
  public void enroll(Person p) {
    if (p.isTeacher()) teachers.add((Teacher)p);
    else student.add((Student)p);
  }
}
```

If you also want to avoid the typecast, try this...

```
abstract class Person {
  public abstract Teacher asTeacher();
  public abstract Student asStudent();
}

class Student extends Person {
  public Student asStudent() { return this; }
  public Teacher asTeacher() { return null; }
}

class Teacher extends Person {
  public Student asStudent() { return null; }
  public Teacher asTeacher() { return this; }
}

class Session extends Person {
  public void enroll(Person p) {
    Teacher t = p.asTeacher();
    if (t != null) teachers.add(t);
    else students.add(p.asStudent());
  }
}
```

This implementation has a minor weakness that it assumes Teachers and Students are the only types of people, but extending it to multiple types is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `p instanceof Student` is that you change the behavior based on something that is not a method invocation, so future changes will be hard (ie. if you add another sub-class of Person).

There are a couple of ways to look at this design problem:

- Why you need to create a hierarchy of `Person`? It's possible in your system that someone that is a student can be a teacher in another course? If that is the case, you have some information about a person, and what changes is the role of that person for a course. So is not convenient to use inheritance for that, use composition and create an object that represents the role of a `Person` in a course.
- You can add a `isTeacher` method, or use a visitor pattern to split the collection. That will be a little bit better than the `instanceof`. But in my opinion the problem is still in the incorrect class hierarchy.

For example, using "roles":

```
enum Role { TEACHER, STUDENT; }

class Session {
   List<SessionEnrolment> enrollments = new ArrayList<>();

   public void enroll(Person p, Role role)
   {
       enrollments.add(new SessionEnrollment(p, role));
   }

   public List<Person> getTeachers() {
      List<Person> result = new ArrayList<>();
      for (SessionEnrolment e : enrollments) {
            if (e.isTeacher()) { result.add(e.getPerson()); }
            return result;
      }
   }
}
```

Using a `isTeacher` method:

```
public void enroll(Person p)
{
    if (p.isTeacher()) { teachers.add(p); } else { students.add(p); }
}
```

As you can see having a `isTeacher` method for all persons looks awkward. And the role solution reflects better the temporal property of being a student or teacher.

You can use a visitor, and it will save you from the ugly `isTeacher` in `Person`; but to me that solution is overcomplicated, and you'll translate the "uglyness" to the `Visitor` interface.

Comment: The visitor interface is where this ugliness belongs. The `Person` is allowed to do something based on whether or not it's a `Teacher` or a `Student`, that's the whole point of polymorphism. Not saying there isn't a better solution, but I'd say visitors are clearly better than replacing `instanceof` with a method that does the same.

Comment: First the hierarchy is wrong, that is my main point. Second calling a `isTeacher` method is polymorphism too: the response depends on the receiver implementation (not in a particular class like with `instanceof`). The visitor will end doing the same but in a more generic way. But if you plan to have other `Person` roles, the problem is that you need to update the `Visitor` interface and all the implementors as the system model grows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you propose with an overloaded method per concrete `Person` implementation, and in addition to that add a Type to the List:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then in your iteration logic you know the type.

Comment: Have you tried it? I did it before you post your answer and didn't work. Otherwise, I heavily suggest you to post the code that backs up your proposed answer.

Comment: Tried what? Instantiating a new List<>()? Changed that to the concrete ArrayList :)

Comment: Tried the overloaded methods and adding the elements of a `List<Person>` using these methods. By the way, the `List<Person>` will contain `Student` and `Teacher` object reference instances.

Comment: That's the point, with my solution there is no List<Person>. By the way I don't see an explicit List<Person> in the question.

Comment: *The idea is that some other code will have a list of people and iterate the list to enroll them into the appropriate sessions as needed... seems like the code that iterates through the list of Person objects*. Translated: `public void enrollPeople(List<Person> peopleList) { for(Person person: peopleList) { enroll(person); } }`

Comment: Omitting how "some other code" might (would) be using it is a mistake on my part. Luiggi's interpretation of that statement would be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it around:

```
class Session {
  StudentList students = new StudentList();
  TeacherList teachers = new TeacherList();

  // add a person to the teaching session.
  // They should be placed into the appropriate lists
  public void enroll(Person p)
  {
     p.addMe(students, teachers);
  }
}

public class StudentList extends ArrayList<Student> {
}

public class TeacherList extends ArrayList<Teacher> {
}

public abstract class Person {
    public abstract void addMe(StudentList sList, TeacherList tList);
}

public class Student extends Person {
    public void addMe(StudentList sList, TeacherList tList) {
        sList.add(this);
    }
}

public class Teacher extends Person {
    public void addMe(StudentList sList, TeacherList tList) {
        tList.add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have a reason. It makes the whole thing work. Why do think it isn't needed?

Comment: By the way, your code does not even compile and shows a bad design.

Comment: Note that if you have a couple more of classes extending this `Person` class you will have to add more parameters to this `addMe` method...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Fair enough. Though it was, in my opinion, showing a technique that answers OP's question about NOT using `instanceof`, you are correct that compilation errors exist. That is fixed. As for more subclasses, that is accurate, but in this case, its pretty much teachers and students that enroll. Anything else is a subclass of those.